# C# how to open all mp3 files using default application

Tags: c#

Is it possible to open the all mp3 files using groove or windows media player the path is something like this "D:\Sound*.mp3" is it possible?

Comment: Do you have some code you can't get to work?

Answer (score 0):

Absolutely. I'm not sure of what you are trying to do (use a C# program to open another program or open and play a program within your C# application) but both are possible and more. The path doesn't matter, as long as there aren't security restrictions on the folder you are trying to load the MP3 from. This link might help:
https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/dd564585(v=vs.85).aspx

Answer (score 0):

https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/dd564585(v=vs.85).aspx
Read this.
Next time post your code and be more specific with what you are trying to do.